# Powershell - calling Move function on email results in extremely verbose output

Tags: powershell

I am moving old messages from one folder to another and when moving them, I get a print out of the object.  I just want to move it without any output unless there is an error.

I am doing:

```
ForEach-Object -Process {
  $psitem.Move($targetFolder)
}
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation or am not sure how to interpret it to disable the verbosity.  It does move okay, but prints out a very long message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try piping the output to `Out-Null`?

```
ForEach-Object -Process {
  $psitem.Move($targetFolder) | Out-Null
}
```

Sometimes you can specify no return information by using the `[void]` prefix.  I do this with StringBuilder objects all the time, as outlined in this great post [Powershell: Concatenate strings using StringBuilder](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-11-20-Powershell-StringBuilder/).  So like this:

```
ForEach-Object -Process {
  [void]$psitem.Move($targetFolder)
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm.  I am new to this language, uh, it is "unique".

Comment: Lots of how it works is common to other .NET languages.  I'm finding that much of my learning comes from C# .NET and other .NET posts using .NET objects/functions, and then I have to figure out how to make PowerShell do the same thing, like with the StringBuilder function (which I first used in C#).  It is an interesting challenge, IMHO.  Glad I could help you out.